# AngularJs ng-repeat display count of matching ID from second list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have two really long list of record (500+), and i'm trying to find an efficient way to display list of items from LIST1 in ng-repeat, but also display the count of items with matching ID from LIST2

Example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list1">
<td>Id</td>
<td>Count of items from LIST2 which matches LIST1.Id with LIST2.Ref.ID</td>
<td>Title</td>
</tr>
```

The sample list is as below:

```
"List1":[
{       
    "Id": 1,    
    "Title": "Red"
},
{       
    "Id": 2,    
    "Title": "Blue"
},
{       
    "Id": 3,    
    "Title": "Green"
},
{       
    "Id": 4,    
    "Title": "Yellow"
},
{       
    "Id": 5,    
    "Title": "Orange"
}

]

"List2":[
 {   "Ref": {
         "ID": 3
        },
    "Title": "John"
 },
{   "Ref": {
         "ID": 3
        },
    "Title": "Jim"
 },
 {   "Ref": {
         "ID": 3
        },
    "Title": "Jane"
 },
 {   "Ref": {
         "ID": 1
        },
    "Title": "don"
 },
  {   "Ref": {
         "ID": 2
        },
    "Title": "Smith"
 },
   {   "Ref": {
         "ID": 4
        },
    "Title": "Doe"
 },
]
```

So ideally from the above example the display would look like:

```
Id | Count | Title
1  -  1  - Red
2  -  1  - Blue
3  -  3  - Green
4  -  1  - Yellow
5  -  0  - Orange
```

Comment: Is JSON creation is also done by you?

Comment: Yes, thats a just a sample. I'm actually getting the list from REST API and both lists are quite huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom filter which returns the count of the items found in list 2.You need to pass two arguments to your custom filter, i.e Id from list1 and your list2.
Try the following:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list1 = [ { "Id": 1, "Title": "Red" }, { "Id": 2, "Title": "Blue" }, { "Id": 3, "Title": "Green" }, { "Id": 4, "Title": "Yellow" }, { "Id": 5, "Title": "Orange" } ];
  $scope.list2 = [ { "Ref": { "ID": 3 }, "Title": "John" }, { "Ref": { "ID": 3 }, "Title": "Jim" }, { "Ref": { "ID": 3 }, "Title": "Jane" }, { "Ref": { "ID": 1 }, "Title": "don" }, { "Ref": { "ID": 2 }, "Title": "Smith" }, { "Ref": { "ID": 4 }, "Title": "Doe" }, ];
});

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(input, list2) {

    var output = list2.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.Ref.ID === input;
    });
    return output.length;

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID|</th>
        <th>Count|</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in list1">
        <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Id | myFilter : list2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks that did it, help much appreciated

Comment: @user366123 Happy to help you :-)